# Difference in the memory utilization in PyCharm and IDLE

Tags: python, memory-management, pycharm, python-idle, cpython

Executing same code in two different code editors (*PyCharm* and *IDLE*) results with different results when using `id` built-in:

```py
obj1 = 1000
obj2 = 1000

print(id(obj1))
print(id(obj2))
```

IDLE output:

```
60194960 ---> obj1

60194992 ---> obj2
```

PyCharm output:

```
6373184 ---> obj1

6373184 ---> obj2
```

Can someone explain this behavior ?

Comment: In IDLE, you were presumably typing that code in line-by-line; since the two assignments of `1000` were executed separately, they created two different `int` objects.  But if the code is run as a single script, the compiler notices that two constants have the same value, and merges them.  (Note that either behavior is perfectly normal; any code that relies on one or the other happening is *broken*.)

Comment: Yeah this seems to be the case. IDLE is an interactive python interpreter. If you try to open a file with IDLE and run it you'll get same IDs for both objects.

Comment: @jasonharper  Can you repost your (correct) anwer as an answer?